# Create blob outputting JSON to a single line (Azure Logic App)

Tags: json, azure, blob, azure-logic-apps, azure-blob-storage

My Create blob function is outputting the entire blob content to a single line instead of a standard JSON format.

Raw Input:

```
[
  {
    "AadTenantId_g": "",
    "ActionIdBefore_g": "",
    "ActionId_g": "",
    "ActionSource_s": "",
    "Activity_s": "",
    "ApplicationId_g": "",
    "ApplicationId_s": "",
    "ApplicationName_s": "",
    "Computer": "",
    "ContentIdBefore_g": "",
    "ContentId_g": "",
    "DataState_s": "",
    "DeviceId_g": "",
    "DeviceId_s": "",
    "DiscoveredInformationTypes_s": "",
    "IPv4_s": "",
    "InformationTypesAbove55_s": "",
    "InformationTypesAbove65_s": "",
    "InformationTypesAbove75_s": "",
    "InformationTypesAbove85_s": "",
    "InformationTypesAbove95_s": "",
    "InformationTypes_s": "",
    "IsLabelChanged_b": null,
    "IsProtectionChanged_b": null,
    "LabelIdBeforeAction_g": "",
    "LabelId_g": "",
    "LabelNameBefore_s": "",
    "LabelName_s": "",
    "LastModifiedBy_s": "",
    "LastModifiedDate_t": null,
    "Location_s": "",
    "LogId_g": "",
    "MG": "",
    "MachineName_s": "",
    "ManagementGroupName": "",
    "ObjectId_s": "",
    "Operation_s": "",
    "ParentLabelNameBefore_s": "",
    "ParentLabelName_s": "",
    "Platform_s": "",
    "ProcessName_g": "",
    "ProcessName_s": "",
    "ProcessVersion_s": "",
    "ProductVersion_s": "",
    "ProtectedBeforeAction_b": null,
    "Protected_b": false,
    "ProtectionOwnerBefore_s": "",
    "ProtectionOwner_s": "",
    "ProtectionTime_t": null,
    "ProtectionTypeBefore_s": "",
    "ProtectionType_s": "",
    "RawData": "",
    "RecommendedLabelId_g": "",
    "RecommendedLabelName_s": "",
    "ResultStatus": "",
    "ResultStatus_s": "",
    "SensitivityChange_s": "",
    "SourceSystem": "",
    "TemplateIdBefore_g": "",
    "TemplateId_g": "",
    "TenantId": "",
    "TimeGenerated": "",
    "Type": "",
    "UserId_s": "",
    "UserJustification_s": "",
    "Version_s": "",
    "Workload_s": "",
    "_ResourceId": "",
    "dynamicInformationTypes_s": null
  }
]
```

Output:

```
[{"AadTenantId_g":"","ActionIdBefore_g":"","ActionId_g":"","ActionSource_s":"","Activity_s":"","ApplicationId_g":"","ApplicationId_s":"","ApplicationName_s":"","Computer":"","ContentIdBefore_g":"","ContentId_g":"","DataState_s":"","DeviceId_g":"","DeviceId_s":"","DiscoveredInformationTypes_s":"","IPv4_s":"","InformationTypesAbove55_s":"","InformationTypesAbove65_s":"","InformationTypesAbove75_s":"","InformationTypesAbove85_s":"","InformationTypesAbove95_s":"","InformationTypes_s":"","IsLabelChanged_b":null,"IsProtectionChanged_b":null,"LabelIdBeforeAction_g":"","LabelId_g":"","LabelNameBefore_s":"","LabelName_s":"","LastModifiedBy_s":"","LastModifiedDate_t":null,"Location_s":"","LogId_g":"","MG":"","MachineName_s":"","ManagementGroupName":"","ObjectId_s":"","Operation_s":"","ParentLabelNameBefore_s":"","ParentLabelName_s":"","Platform_s":"","ProcessName_g":"","ProcessName_s":"","ProcessVersion_s":"","ProductVersion_s":"","ProtectedBeforeAction_b":null,"Protected_b":false,"ProtectionOwnerBefore_s":"","ProtectionOwner_s":"","ProtectionTime_t":null,"ProtectionTypeBefore_s":"","ProtectionType_s":"","RawData":"","RecommendedLabelId_g":"","RecommendedLabelName_s":"","ResultStatus":"","ResultStatus_s":"","SensitivityChange_s":"","SourceSystem":"","TemplateIdBefore_g":"","TemplateId_g":"","TenantId":"","TimeGenerated":"","Type":"","UserId_s":"","UserJustification_s":"","Version_s":"","Workload_s":"","_ResourceId":"","dynamicInformationTypes_s":null}]
```

I was thinking the MediaType of the body was the issue, since **MediaType = application/octet-stream**.

This issue is purely located at the **Create blob** stage.

Any help would be appreciated - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could "manually" added a row like this in the definition of the "create blob" connector.

```
"headers": {
"content-type": "application/json"
}
```

Comment: I have this header set already.
Do you understand why the blob would format the JSON to a single line?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see your Create blob function, but I solved this problem by adding optional parameters to JSON.stringify() method, which I use to prepare my JSON data to upload:

`JSON.stringify(myJson, null, 4)`

The value *null* is for *replacer* parameter, which we dont use and number 4 represents space parameter -> number of spaces of indentation -> simply it makes JSON look like readable JSON:)